# Movie where boy finds powerful space rocks

Tags: story-identification, movie

Not too many details as I can't recall much. 2005-ish(?) live-action American film where a boy with straight-ish brown hair finds glowing stones (not gems, but rocks with glowing blue portions) that hold some kind of power. The government, or some other kind of science officials, somehow get their hands on it, but the boy insists that "They're just.. rocks." I distinctly remember a scene where the little sister is reaching through an energy field produced by the rocks and he yells something at her, probably to have her get back.

Sorry this isn't much info, will edit if I remember anything else.

Comment: Did the rocks actually do anything other than float? Was this set in America?

Comment: There was some other power that the rocks had, but I don't really remember what it was. I watched this when I was only 6 or so years old, so my memories are pretty scarce.

Comment: It was _made_ in America (stating that it was not a foreign movie), and I am very certain that it was set in America as well.

Comment: definitely sounds like "The Last Mimzy" - great film btw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't stress enough for how long I've been wanting to find a movie so similar to this one.
Today it finally happened and I think it's the same one you were looking for.
It's called ***[The Last Mimzy](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0768212/)*** (2007) and it fits all of your descriptions perfectly.

> Two siblings begin to develop special talents after they find a mysterious box of toys. Soon the kids, their parents, and even their teacher are drawn into a strange new world and find a task ahead of them that is far more important than any of them could imagine!

Comment: This is most likely the right answer based on the OP.

Comment: Oh, my!  Somebody made a movie from the short story [*Mimsy Were the Borogroves*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mimsy_Were_the_Borogoves)

Comment: Thank you! found at long last!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe *Shorts*, written by Robert Rodriguez, and released in 2008?

Some common elements:
The fundamental description matches in its entirety: *2005-ish(?) live-action American film where a boy finds glowing stones (not gems, but rocks with glowing portions) that hold some kind of power.*

Date is right-ish: 2008 is close-ish to 2005-ish.

Live-action: check.

American film: large-budget WB release with well-known director.

Character & story are right: a boy finds glowing stones (not gems, but rocks with glowing portions) that hold some kind of power.

Brother & Sister: main protagonist has a bratty little sister (played by Kat Dennings)

Nefarious military-industrial complex pseudo government organization: Black Box Agency led by James Spader’s Mr. Black seeks the stones and their power.

Comment: No, this isn't it. I'd say, judging by the trailer, the only similarity is that a boy finds a space rock with special powers.